# How should I represent groupings of emails with Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, model

For example I have an application that is like an email and have various sections (groups of email):

- Inbox
- Sent
- Special x (some of them also exists in the inbox)
- Trash

All those groups contains emails, let's call Email model. Now my question is:

1. Should I use one collection for all the 4 groups?
2. Or should I use one collection for each group?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, store different group messages into one collection will cause problem for data maintaining (refresh, render view).

You can nest email messages collection inside of email group model. Each mail group has one message pool and you can fetch these messages easily.

e.g.,

**MailBox Model**

```
var MailBox = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //nest messages collection inside of model
        this.messages = new Messages();
        this.messages.url = "your/path/"+this.id+"/to/RESTful/";
    }
});
```

**Message Model**

```
var Message = Backbone.Model.extend(function(){});
```

**Messages Collection**

```
var Messages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Message
});
```

**Instantiate a MailBox model instance**

```
var sentBox = new MailBox({id:"sent"});
//fetch messages in this box
sentBox.collection.fetch();

var inBox = new MailBox({id:"in"});
//fetch messages in this box
sentBox.collection.fetch();
```

**Your messages list view onSync Handler**

```
var MessageListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //register messages syn event
        this.listenTo(this.model.messages,"sync",this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.model.messages.each(function(msg){
            //merge message model data and view
        });
    }
});
```

You can change the model of message list view when switch between inbox and sent box.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Model in this case will be "Email Message", so it is better to use Collection for each group named "Inbox", "Sent" etc., which is based on "Email Message" model.

Ofcourse you can also use a collection named "Group", but in my opinion it is bad idea.